# cross-platform html widget for pygtk

Tags: python, cross-platform, pyqt, pygtk, html-rendering

I'm trying to write a small gui app in pygtk which needs an html-rendering widget.  I'd like to be able to use it in a windows environment.

Currently I'm using pywebkitgtk on my GNU/Linux system, and it works extremely well, but it seems it's not possible to use this on Windows at this time.

Can anyone give me any suggestions on how to proceed?  Do I need to work out how to embed IE using COM objects under Windows, and stick with pywebkitgtk on GNU/Linux?

I'm at an early stage, and am prepared to jettison pygtk in favour of another toolkit, say pyqt, if it affords a simpler solution (though I'd sooner stick with pygtk if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, having developed cross-platform applications with both PyQt and PyGTK, you should consider moving to PyQt. It comes with a browser widget by default which runs fine on all platforms, and support for non-Linux platforms is outstanding compared to PyGTK. For PyGTK, you will have to be prepared building PyGObject/PyCairo/PyGTK, or even the full stack, yourself on Windows and Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [gtkhtml2](http://www.mail-archive.com/pygtk@daa.com.au/msg16368.html), but might not solve your problem on Windows. I haven't used it before myself. Another option to consider is pymozembed, to embed a Mozilla browser window in your GTK app.